# How to take the attendance of all the attendees on a aem event using Adobe campaign?

Tags: events, adobe, aem, neolane

Context:
-       We are managing events in Campaign
-       A visitor can register for an event via AEM website that includes an iframe to the registration form hosted on Campaign

Question:
Does campaign provide a web report or web page listing all attendees registered for a specific event?
If yes from the list of attendees for a specific event do we have the possibility to confirm (via a checkbox for example) when the attendee attends the event (manual tick from the event organiser)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question part 1**: Does campaign provide a web report or web page listing all attendees registered for a specific event?

**Yes** Adobe campaign provide reports for listing all attendees for one event or multiple events.
Follow the following steps to create reports.

1. Go adminstration>configurations>reports create new report.
2. Select the selection type from report view i. global, multiple
   selection or single selection.
   [image: screen for selection]
3. Create the query to fetch the records that you want to display in the
   report.
4. Drag and drop a page form to the workflow space.
5. Add a table in the form to display the list all of all records.
6. Add the context data to the table and do the formatting to display
   the data.
   [image: form/table screen]

**Question part 2**: If yes from the list of attendees for a specific event do we have the possibility to confirm (via a checkbox for example) when the attendee attends the event (manual tick from the event organiser)?

**No**

**Solution:**

1. create a custom extension to take the attendance(update the table
   record from web).Follow all the steps mentioned in link [custom
   extension](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/extending/extending-adobe-campaign/creating-custom-form-mappings.html)
2. call the logon method in adobe campaign from form to get the session
   token.
3. Add two buttons in form i. present, absent.
4. call(ajax or page load) the custom url for custom extension with the required parameters and update the record.

You are all set :)